# Finding the Area of the Largest Triangle in a Certain Curve

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was studying for some quizzes when I encountered this problem. It goes like this:

> Find the area of the largest triangle cut from the first quadrant by a line tangent to the curve $y = e^{-x}$

My work:

This is how I imagined the problem:

[image]

The area of the triangle as described in the picture above is $A = \frac{1}{2} x y.$ Since $y = e^{-x},$ then the area would be 
$A = \frac{1}{2} x e^{-x}$

We need to maximize the area, so we get the derivative of the area $A.$

The derivative of $A = \frac{1}{2} x e^{-x}$ is $\frac{dA}{dx} = \frac{1}{2} (-xe^{-x} + e^{-x})$ or:
$$\frac{dA}{dx} = e^{-x} \left(  \frac{-x}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \right)$$

To get the maximum area of the triangle, we set $\frac{dA}{dx}$ to zero.

$$\frac{dA}{dx} = e^{-x} \left(  \frac{-x}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \right)$$
$$0 = e^{-x} \left(  \frac{-x}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \right)$$

So we got: $e^-x = 0$ and  $ \frac{-x}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = 0 $

Getting the value of $x$ in the expression $e^{-x} = 0,$ $x$ is undefined.
Getting the value of $x$ in the expression $\frac{-x}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = 0,$ $x =1$.

To verify that $x = 1$ is the value that gives the maximum area, we do a First Derivative Test. Making the $x =1 $ as the critical/ base point, we try $x = 0.32$ and $x = 99.$

If $x = 0.32,$ the the value of the derivative is $$\frac{dA}{dx} = e^{-(0.32)} \left(  \frac{-(0.32)}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \right) = + 0.2469$$
If $x = 99,$ the the value of the derivative is $$\frac{dA}{dx} = e^{-(99)} \left(  \frac{-(99)}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \right) = -4.955 \times 10^{42}$$

If the sign of derivative changes from (+,0,-), then the critical point is the maximum point, which is $x = 1.$

At this point, I got the slope of 1, which comes from $x = 1.$ I don't know what to do next. How do you get the area of the
 largest triangle that can be cut from the first quadrant by a line tangent to the curve $y = e^x$ ?

Comment: where exactly is the triangle situated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any line can be described by an equation of the form $y=mx+b$, where $m$ is the slope and $b$ is the $y$-intercept.  Assuming that $m<0$ and $b>0$, the region bounded by the line and the two axes will be bounded and will, in fact, be a triangle.  The base of this triangle will be the segment from the origin to the $x$-intercept, and the height of this triangle will be the segment from the origin to the $y$-intercept.  These are given by
$$ \text{$y$-intercept: $(0,b)$}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\text{$x$-intercept: $(0,-\tfrac{b}{m})$}.
$$
Thus the area of such a triangle is given by
$$
\text{Area} = \frac{1}{2} \text{base}\times\text{height} = \frac{1}{2} \left(-\frac{b}{m} \right) m = -\frac{1}{2} \frac{b^2}{m}.$$
Note that since we have assumed that $m < 0$, it follows that the area is nonnegative, which is reassuring.

Next, note that an equation for a line tangent to the graph of $f$ at a point $(a,f(a))$ is given by the point-slope equation as
$$ y - f(a) = f'(a) (x-a)
\implies y = \underbrace{f'(a)}_{=m}x + \underbrace{\left[f(a) - af'(a)\right]}_{=b}.$$
Hence if $a \ge 0$, the equation of the tangent line to $e^{-x}$ at $a$ is given by
$$
y
= \left.\frac{d}{dt} e^{-t} \right|_{t=a}x + \left[ e^{-a} - a\left.\frac{d}{dt} e^{-t} \right|_{t=a} \right]
= \underbrace{-e^{-a}}_{=m}x + \underbrace{\left[ e^{-a} + a e^{-a}\right]}_{=b}.
$$
Observe that this line has negative slope and positive $y$-intercept, thus we can apply the above result to conclude that the triangle bounded by the tangent line and the axes has area
$$
\text{Area}
= \frac{1}{2} \frac{\left[ e^{-a} + a e^{-a}\right]^2}{e^{-a}}
= \frac{1}{2} \left(e^{-a} + 2ae^{-a} + a^2 e^{-a}\right)
$$
Since we want to maximize the area, set the derivative (with respect to $a$) equal to zero, and solve for $a$.  This gives us
\begin{align}
0 &= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a} \text{Area} \\
&= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a} \frac{1}{2} \left(e^{-a} + 2ae^{-a} + a^2 e^{-a}\right) \\
&= (1-a^2) e^{-a}.
\end{align}
This is possible if and only if $a=1$ (since we have already assumed that $a>0$).  Therefore the area of the triangle-of-interest is maximized when $a=1$, i.e. we are interested in the line tangent to $y=e^{-x}$ at the point $(1,e^{-1})$.  The area of this triangle is given by
\begin{align}
\text{Area}
&= \left. \frac{1}{2} \left(e^{-a} + 2ae^{-a} + a^2 e^{-a}\right) \right|_{a=1} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left(e^{-1} + 2e^{-1} + e^{-1}\right) \\
&= 2e^{-1}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you want the area of the triangle in the first quadrant bounded by the tangent line and the axes.

Based on that assumption, if $(x,y) = (t,e^{-t})$ is the point of tangency, the area is not $\frac{1}{2}xy$.

Instead, leaving $t$ unknown, find the equation of the tangent line in terms of $t$, then find the $x$ and $y$ intercepts, also in terms of $t$. Once you have the intercepts, you can express the area of the triangle as a function of $t$. That's the function you want to maximize.

Can you finish it?

Comment: you're right....I want the area of the triangle in the first quadrant bounded by the tangent line and the axes.

Answer (score 0):

Let's just deal with some general strictly decreasing convex (enough) differentiable function $f$. Then the formula for a tangent line at point $t$ is $$y = f'(t)(x-t)+f(t).$$ By setting $x = 0$ and $y = 0$, we get that tangent line at $t$ intersects the axes at points $(a(t),0)$ and $(0,b(t))$ where

\begin{align}
a(t) &= \frac{tf'(t)-f(t)}{f'(t)},\\ 
b(t) &= f(t)-tf'(t).
\end{align}

The area of the triangle is then $\frac 12 |a(t)b(t)|$. Hence, we are looking for maximum of function

$$A(t) = -\frac{(f'(t)t-f(t))^2}{2f'(t)}.$$ *(Note: we don't need absolute value since $f$ was assumed to be strictly decreasing.)*

Thus, if there is a triangle of maximum area , we are looking for point such that $$A'(t) = 0\iff \left( \frac{f(t)^2}{f'(t)^2}-t^2 \right)f''(t) = 0.$$

We assumed $f$ to be convex, so $f''(t)>0$ and thus, it must be that $$\frac{f(t)^2}{f'(t)^2}=t^2 \iff \left|\frac{f(t)}{f'(t)}\right| = |t|.$$

Finally, letting $f(x) = e^{-x}$ gives us $|t| = 1$. Now, notice that condition "cut from the first quadrant" implies that $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ must be positive, i.e. $f(t)-f'(t)t > 0$. But, for $t = -1$, we have $f(t)-f'(t)t = 0$ (which implies that the tangent line is passing through origin), so we are left with $t = 1$, for which we get $A(1) = 2e^{-1}$.

Technically, we still need to check that this is maximum. We have that $$A'(t) = \frac 12\left( \frac{f(t)^2}{f'(t)^2}-t^2 \right)f''(t) = \frac 12(1-t^2)e^{-t}\implies A''(t) = -te^{-t}-\frac 12(1-t^2)e^{-t}$$ and so $A''(1) = -e^{-1} < 0$.